# Das Verb "gelten" mit dem Dativ

Tags: meaning-in-context

Im Satz:

> Fest terminierte Quälerei im Hallenbad **gilt** auch sportbegeisterten Teenies **nichts gegen** den spontanen Nachmittag im Freibad.

lässt sich das Verb **gelten** mit keiner der vom Duden empfohlenen Bedeutungen erklären. Was heißt es in diesem Fall?

Comment: nichts gelten = wertlos sein (im Vergleich).

Comment: Der Satz ist völlig unverständlich für mich, auch wenn er grammatikalisch korrekt ist. Ich habe ihn nun dreimal gelesen und bekomme gerade eine Ahnung davon, was ausgesagt werden soll. Vielleicht: _Auch sportbegeisterte Jugendliche ziehen den spontanen Nachmittag im Freibad vor, statt nach einem festen Termin im Hallenbad (andere zu quälen/ gequält zu werden/ zuzuschauen, während andere gequält werden/ ...)_?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich *Selbst das beste gekochte Gemüse gilt mir nichts gegen ein gescheites Steak vom Grill* - Hilft das? Es ist dieselbe Konstruktion wie der Beispielsatz, nur mit weniger Lametta.

Comment: @tofro: Wenn's doch nur Lametta wär' ...

Comment: Das Schlimmste ist ja, dass der Satz aus einem DaF-Lehrwerk stammt...

Comment: DaF. Kommt mir auch so vor. Hört sich auch für Muttersprachler wie 'ne Fremdsprache an...

Comment: @VollDerChecker Welches Buch ist es? Stammt der Textausschnitt darin aus einem anderem Medium?

Comment: "Fit für das DSD II", Hueber Verlag. Die Quelle ist angeblich Paseler Anzeiger, was aber frei erfunden ist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das ist etwas ungewöhnlich formuliert, aber doch im Rahmen der Bedeutung von "gelten" im Sinne von "[etwas] Wert sein", [Bedeutung Nr. 1 bei DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gelten)

Für die Teenies ist "die terminierte Quälerei im Hallenbad" im Vergleich zu einem "spontanen Nachmittag im Freibad" "nichts Wert". Sie bevorzugen also letzteres.